# TypeScript implicit type inferencing through property in Object constructor does not work

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

As described in the comments within the code, explicitly supplying the specific type for the generic in the class works and returns the right type when calling the getter function.

I would like this to work by implicit inference as well.
In that case it correctly infers the keys of the generic, but all of it's values are types of `unknown`.

Is there any way to make the implicit inference work like the explicit ones?

Here is the code in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgFVBgAUoIw0YFgBnOAbwCg4W4ByG4GKpAcxoB0IAJ4AvfMIpsAXHCQBXALYAjNAG5mrBDQCSKNFlwB5JLOUQIAG2CYkGgL6NGoSLDjYISGvDBkKsYT0AE1B8CABlGCh5bBh5KGAgo2UAKwBZTDBZejgAbWQQkEQkOABrYGEIdAIiUnJKahoAXVkFFTQ4ezgAXgZNFg4uHn4hMQkpWQAGABp+xF19DBxgE1kAJkZHZ3BoeGxLTBo6AHFgJDQEbD1UJdwAHlPzqEu6-ypaAD4+1ndPb2jYtAABS+BAAN0wqDgvnqAWCoQiURicQSyXSmWyeQKoGKZQqVTgjwu2FeDVoLTkSlUUE6AEoGFsfmB5MpLJc4LwuKTYI0gfSmD8fgB6IX0LraOAwCx44BgSUACwlNCQCDAFHgNHluwEcAASjZLHAAO7QSxBX4hY0QeRmuAJFElTDQvwdCCpYCxARzH72+IlMVwQ6Es7E7nvGgaH6OLYigCi4DZ2AQqEswjg8hoyF4NRAJBdPNocHQ0GDTxe+fDVqgpRojA8XngLkTyZ6cmARtLxOuBmWd0IubDjQ+IIrgSQhTCkQBKMSaIyYFpGnr3jgTYQydedF6a6TMAEnLzsPDfLUcBF8qDMEkeH7h7ejScIp0ijAzZTaeQ6AufE7zxJFcaBUyHkXh5QVPA3RSD0fDIMEEBCc1kHA34G2nEsgggQskAgeATWrOs-ngBAXzfVtzg7Ik-27W5gBHI8xwnRFp3iWdUnnRcCIbRASMuDc-C3bjX14vcD0HWgTzPIULzoK8KAYQZuCzQQRHEa8ZHTJBSmwo0kGmeZqMMFZTA0rSIB0+wgA)

```
export interface TextProperties {
    'settings.xyzType': number;
    isInterfaceOn: boolean;
}

export const propertyIndexToStructuredObjMap: { [index in keyof TextProperties]: number } = {
    'settings.xyzType': 0,
    isInterfaceOn: 2
}

export class GenericInterface<GenericProperties> {
    constructor(private propertyIndexToStructureObjMap: { [index in keyof GenericProperties]: number }) {}

    public getProperties() {
        //{} is too keep this snippet short. Real world code would return a proper object.
        return {} as GenericProperties;
    }
}

//Explicitely using TextProperties for GenericProperties works
const explicit = new GenericInterface<TextProperties>(propertyIndexToStructuredObjMap);
const expliitProps = explicit.getProperties(); //has type TextProperties

//Implicitely infering GenericProperties through the object provided in the constructor does not work
const implicit = new GenericInterface(propertyIndexToStructuredObjMap);
const implicitProps = implicit.getProperties(); //has type {'settings.xyzType': unknown, isInterfaceOn: unknown}
```

Comment: You wish to create a generic class, however your constructor allows an object where the values of the properties are always of type number? So it would not allow values of boolean for example? It looks like you're trying to transform the types of your input value? It's a little unclear

Comment: @DamianGreen Ultimately this function should transform an array like: [0, 'foo', true] into something like {'setting.xyzType': 0, isInterfaceOn: true};
The Object propertyIndexToStructureObjMap contains a mapping between property names and the indexes in the source array. GenericProperties contains a mapping between property names and their types.

I want this to be generic to allow having different mappings.
I left out the logic mapping the array into this object as I got that part working. My problem is the typing is not correctly infered implicitly as shown in the code above.

Comment: so `'settings.xyzType' is meant to references a  type inside a nested object `settings` ?